# PC freeze after some time with Barcode Scanners by JS script?

Tags: javascript

The Problem with my JS code is that the Complet PC with the Barcode scanner is freezing, so we need to Hard reset the PC system. I come with a friend to no conclude why this is happening.

The JS code is just there to trigger the button in the HTML to start the PHP code to run. We tested it on another machine and get the same problem. With the JS script.
In my test System without Barcode Scanner I don't get this problem.
We tried to insert e.preventDefault() in case that should be the Problem. But still, happen.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("#scan_field").focus();
            $(document).on("keyup", "#scan_field", function() {
                let currentText = $(this).val();
                if(
                    (currentText.indexOf("BA") !== -1 && currentText.length === 16) ||
                    (
                        (currentText.indexOf("3S") !== -1 || currentText.indexOf("CF") !== -1)
                        &&
                        currentText.length === 13
                    )
                ) {
                   $("#submit_scan_parcel").trigger("click");

                   e.preventDefault();
                   return true;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

this code should not freeze an entire PC System even when working with it some Houres.

But Momently the System´s freeze complete and you have to make a Hard reset.
I use this little code on other sites that are not used so often and there is no problem with this but what's wrong here?

Comment: The way you describe it indicates that the problem is related to the barcode scanner.

Comment: yes I was thinking that too.
But was not rly right if i have not somthing fishy in my JS code